# C multilevel inheritance recursion

Tags: c, inheritance

I have a project that must be in C (just to avoid the use C++ arguments).

The project depends on virtual tables and pointers to implement polymorphism.

Im stuck however in implementing super constructors from multi-level inheritance.

An example structure is:

```
            Base Object
            /\       /\
Constructed Object       Simple Object
   /\
SpecificConstructed
```

All objects have a name and a class.
Constructed objects may have a list of sub objects for example.
As simple object may only add a single value.

Base Object is just defined as:

```
struct _object {
     struct _class *class;
     char *name;
}
```

Class is where the virtual table is:

```
struct _class {
     struct _class *super;
     char *name;
     size_t size;
     void* (*init)(void *_this, char *name);
     ...
}
```

A constructed object is:

```
struct _constructed_object {
    struct _object base;
    void* components; //a list of sub objects for example
}
```

A sample simple object is:

```
 struct _simple_object {
    struct _object base;
    unsigned char value; //a simple value for this specific type
 }
```

So every object has a class, and classes can have supers, specially for the SpecificConstructed -> Constructed.

The definitions i have:

```
 struct _class base = {0, "Base", sizeof(struct _object), base_init};
 struct _class constructed = {&base, "Constructed", sizeof(struct _constructed_object}, constructed_init};
 struct _class specific = {&constructed, "SpecificConstructed", sizeof(struct _constructed_object), specific_init};
 struct _class simple = {&base, "SimpleOBject", sizeof(struct _simple_object}, simple_init};
```

This definition allows me to create objects of specify classes using a function:

```
new(struct _class *a_class) {
    ...
    struct _object *o = calloc(1, a_class->size);
    o->class = a_class;
    o = a_class->init(o);
    return o;
}
```

The idea is if i do:

```
 new(SpecificConstructed)
```

New would create the appropriate space (sizeof(struct _constructed_object)), it would call "specific_init", which in turn would call "constructed_init" (it's super), which finally would call "base_init" (it's super). However the flow is specific_init, constructed_init, specific_init, constructed_init ...

The function i have for calling the supers initializer:

```
void* super_init(void* _this, char *name){
    struct _object *o = (struct _object*)_this;
    const struct _class *c = o->class;
    const struct _class *s = c->super;
    return (s && s->init) ? s->init(_this, name) : _this;
}
```

The simple (to - super) base method call works since i can just call the supers init.

But for the specific constructed, calling super takes me to the constructed object which is the correct step, but then instead of the constructed sending me up to the base_init, it sends me back to the specific_init call. This happens since I'm passing the same _this object which starts with the class specific i understand that, but not sure how to fix it and if its actually possible to fix?

Ive read the Object Oriented C book, but it deals with one-level inheritance Circle->Point, and the Metaclasses chapter just flew over my head. Ive also looked at the Objective-C runtime to see how that handles it, but it also has metaclasses and that i can't comprehend at the moment.

Comment: It is not very clear how your implementation of `struct _class` is supposed to work. Each class have its own set of methods and their signatures differ. How a one-size-fits-all `struct _class` is going to take care of that? It is also not very clear whether you want multiple inheritance or just multiple levels of inheritance.

Comment: i mean multiple levels of inheritance not multiple inheritance, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super_init` can't work like that, it needs **class** on which to call super, otherwise (as you discovered) the immediate superclass constructor ends up calling itself over and over. Since each class knows its parent, it can call superclass's init directly. For example, `simple.init` will call `specific.init`, which will in turn call `constructed.init`, and so on.

If you insist on a function to do that for you, you will have to give it the class so it can (trivially) invoke the constructor of the superclass. [`super` in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) is an example of such a design. Python 3 introduces a simpler-to-use `super`, but it required support from the compiler to figure out the correct class to pass to the underlying function.

Comment: A generic function cannot call a superclass constructor. It has no idea which arguments to pass to it.

Comment: @n.m. The constructors in the OP's design have fixed arguments - instance and a `name`.

Comment: Seems like there is no other way around, I'm marking this as an answer until something better (if any comes around). Also the fact that i don't use variadic arguments helps.

Comment: @user4815162342 This makes the design rather non-generic, but hey, whatever works.

Comment: @n.m. One obvious modification would be for `init` functions to accept `va_list` arguments, a la `vprintf`. That should enable both a generic `new` and (with some effort) constructor chaining.

Comment: @user4815162342 the book does use variadic constructors, but no chaining (frankly I have no idea how it could ever be possible automatically; all OO languages I know require to call the parent constructor explicitly).

Comment: @n.m. Haven't read the book, but the question doesn't seem to ask for automatic parent constructor invocation. It says, *new... would call "specific_init", which in turn would call "constructed_init" (it's super), which finally would call "base_init" (it's super).* I expect that `va_list`-declared constructors it harder to chain because each chained call must go through hoops to create the `va_list`.

Comment: @user4815162342 The user writes all constructors, therefore the user must insert all super constructor calls in them. Don't see anything automatic here.

Comment: @n.m. Neither do I. I was responding to the part of your comment stating "I have no idea how it could ever be possible automatically" - AFAICT automaticity was never requested in the first place. Maybe my comment that *that should enable both a generic `new` and (with some effort) constructor chaining* was unclear - the "generic" adjective was intended to apply only to the `new` part, not to "constructor chaining".

Answer (score 1):

This is awesome stuff, I did a bit of that kind of stuff in C in the early nineties, before moving on to C++.

<sub>Unfortunately, despite the fact that your question is quite long, it is still a bit vague because it is not showing us certain things, like what is a "constructed object", (why are you calling it like that,) what is the difference between "constructed object" and "simple object", and what is "the simple->base method call". Also, why the `size`?  Also, I think that some sample code showing the actual problem with the invocation of the constructors is necessary.</sub>

The one thing that I can tell you right now about this design is that it strikes me as odd that you are storing a pointer to the constructor in the Virtual Method Table.  In all object oriented languages that I know, (C++, Java, C#) constructors are *never* virtual; they look a lot more like "static" methods, which in C parlance are just plain link-by-name methods.  This works fine, because every class has built-in, absolutely certain, unalterable knowledge of who its base class is.

Anyhow, chained constructor invocation is supposed to happen like this:

```
void basemost_init( struct basemost* this, char* name )
{
    this->class = &basemost_class;
    this->name = name;
    ...
}

void intermediate_init( struct intermediate* this, char* name )
{
    basemost_init( &this->base, name );
    this->class = &intermediate_class;
    ...
}

void descendant_init( struct descendant* this, char* name )
{
    intermediate_init( &this->base, name );
    this->class = &descendant_class;
    ...
}
```

**Edit** (after some clarifications)

If you want it to look cool at the allocation end, perhaps try something like this:  (I am not sure how well I remember my C syntax, so please excuse any minor inaccuracies.)

```
struct descendant* new_descendant( char* name )
{
    struct descendant* this = malloc( sizeof struct descendant );
    descendant_init( this, name );
    return this;
}
```

This way, you don't need a `size` anymore. Also, note that you can pass as many constructor arguments as you want, without being restricted to a fixed, predetermined number of arguments, (which I consider to be extremely important,) and without having to use variadic constructors.

You may also be able to achieve the same thing with a `#define` macro for all classes, if you promise to use consistent naming, so that the name of each constructor can always be computed as `structname##_init`, but I am not sure how to pass arbitrary constructor parameters *after the `this` pointer* through a macro in C.  Anyhow, I prefer to avoid macros unless they are absolutely necessary, and in this case they are not.

Comment: Ive edited the question a bit, hope it helps. Im using the method used in the OOC book, the idea is that every class has a pointer to an initializer which the object uses. Every class initializes the object. The size allows me to do: new(struct _class) -> which would malloc the appropriate size for the instance and then call init on it.

Comment: "every class has a pointer to an initializer which the object uses" That's a bad idea ad OOC is a bad and misguided book.

Comment: They put `init` in the class descriptor so that they can have uniform syntax for `new`. But this creates a huge drawback: every class now has to have just one constructor, and every constructor must be a variadic function. This is totally unacceptable.

Comment: Once you decide to use C for OOP, you have to take it for a fact that you are *not* going to have such luxuries as elegant and terse syntax for doing everything. To me, the virtual constructor appears to be a hack which was invented to make allocation look terse, but it messes with the overall design of things, so it is a very bad idea.  Anyhow, there may be ways to keep things looking terse without this hack, let me think about it a bit.

Comment: @n.m. Isn't `init` in the class descriptior fairly standard OOP design? C++, Java, Python, and Perl all seem to have some version of it. In the design shown above, constructors aren't variadic, they're argument-less, which probably makes it hard to have them do something useful. I haven't read the book, so I can't tell how much the OP diverged from the material presented there.

Comment: @user4815162342 They are variadic in the book. I skimmed over it. They introduce inheritance with the Circle is-a Point hierarchy. Blergh.

Comment: OK, "bad and misguided" are probably too strong words. I still think it could be better in many respects though.